# How we can convert this customer group dropdown select to multi select dropdown in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to convert this customer group dropdown select to a multi-select dropdown in Magento 2.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the below code in your custom module's `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <settings>
                <templates>
                    <filters>
                        <select>
                            <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                            <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                        </select>
                    </filters>
                </templates>
            </settings>
            <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options"/>
                    <caption translate="true">All Store Views</caption>
                    <label translate="true">Purchase Point</label>
                    <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

**Note:** In this case, you will get all the select filters as Multiselect. Please check the attached screenshots

[image]

[image]

If you want to change customer group column only as multiselect then refer the `vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-catalog-ui/view/adminhtml/ui_component/media_gallery_category_listing.xml` file `asset_id` filter column

Comment: where i will add this refer for only customer group multiselect

Comment: i just want to change for customer group

Comment: I am not sure, whether it is possible for single column, but in core Magento module they achieved in a single column. The feature achieved core file is `vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-catalog-ui/view/adminhtml/ui_component/media_gallery_category_listing.xml` filter `asset_id` column. Pls refer this file

Comment: ok fine thanks for  it